# grep keeps printing the same string

Tags: grep

I typed `grep ch->spl[4] *` into my shell to look for something in a mud code and its broken grep now.
Any time I try to grep anything pretty much it puts the spl[4] before the filename like this.

```
[:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:spl[4]:act_wiz.c:           if ( vch->timer > 0 )
```

Question is how do I clear/stop this so I can get my normal grep back?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling grep? Use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grep`.

Comment: It is possible the command has resulted in extra files in your current directory because of the '>' symbol being interpreted as an output redirection operator. What is the output of 'ls' in the current directory? Do you have any files called 'spl[4]' or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `grep ch->spl[4] *` do? It will search for the pattern `ch-` in all files (and directories) in your current directory and save the result in the file `spl[4]`. To avoid this, you should **always** quote your grep patterns:

```
grep "ch->spl[4]" *
```

Still, the behavior you describe is very strange, there is no reason why this would have changed you your `grep` works. What is probably happening is that you keep searching through the `spl[4]`  file (because you are grepping `*`) and that file contains the output you see. Chances are that if you delete it, things will go back to normal.

Comment: Thanks Terdon that was exactly it. It had created a file called spl[4] and a few other variations. On deleting those it went back to normal.